# Add OpenLayers map on map canvas with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, openstreetmap, mapcanvas

I have map canvas with two shapesfiles, and I want to add OSM map behind. My code for this is:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QDockWidget, QWidget
from osgeo import gdal
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

layerInput = QgsVectorLayer('path to shape file1', "file 1", "ogr")
layerInputShape = QgsVectorLayer('path to shape file2', "file 2", "ogr")


# canvas settings
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)


#defining OSM
xml = """<GDAL_WMS>
<Service name="TMS">
<ServerUrl>http://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</
ServerUrl>
</Service>
<DataWindow>
<TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
<TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
<TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
<YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>EPSG:4326</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>"""
vfn = "/vsimem/osm.xml"
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vfn, xml)
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer(vfn, "OSM")

# puting both vector layers on canvas
extent = QgsRectangle()
layers = []
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerInput)
extent.combineExtentWith(layerInput.extent())
layers.append(layerInput)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerInputShape)
extent.combineExtentWith(layerInputShape.extent())
layers.append(layerInputShape)


#puting osm on canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rasterLyr)
extent.combineExtentWith(rasterLyr.extent())
layers.append(rasterLyr)

extent.scale(1.1)
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.setLayers(layers)

# for legend
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(root, canvas)
model = QgsLayerTreeModel(root)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeRename)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
view = QgsLayerTreeView()
view.setModel(model)
view.show()

# embed the view and canvas into dock widget
layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(view)
layout.addWidget(canvas)
docked = QDockWidget()
docked.setContentsMargins(9, 9, 9, 9)
dockedWidget = QWidget()
docked.setWidget(dockedWidget)
docked.setWindowTitle('title')
dockedWidget.setLayout(layout)
docked.show()


# canvas properties
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerInput)
canvas.setExtent(layerInput.extent())
canvas.setLayers([layerInput])

canvas.refresh()
canvas.show()
app.exec_()
```

But on the map canvas, I just get shapefiles, without OSM map.

Comment: Does it work inside QGIS?

Comment: I try it in python qgis console and it's same, I don't get an error or something, but on map canvas, I get only vector layers. It would be easier if I know where the mistake is. :/

Comment: I've experienced something similar when trying to add a WMS or XYZ tile service layer through the GUI. If you make any kind of mistake, or your link is not valid, you don't get an error message. The layer simply doesn't appear. It's very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't have any code, I've only attempted this through the GUI (Graphical User Interface, ie by clicking buttons not writing code). I would suggest you try adding your WMS layer that way first, to make sure at least the URL is correct.

Comment: How about using the OpenLayers plugin to an OSM layer?